# Calling a database class: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required form parameter 'configuration'

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to make my first ever call to the database using Blazor. I have added connection strings into `appsettings.json`, and logically speaking, it seems ok to me.

However, when I call my class `Data.dbFuctions db = new Data.dbFuctions();` Visual Studio tells me the following:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required form parameter 'configuration'

How can I fix this, & what am I doing wrong? (sorry if it's simple, I'm new to Blazor).

**.Razor page**

```
@page "/"
@using Linkington.Data
@inject dbFuctions dbFuctions

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code{
    Data.dbFuctions db = new Data.dbFuctions();  // me trying to call the class
}
```

**My database class**

```
//DB CONNECTION
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public dbFuctions(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this._configuration = configuration;
}

// PUBLIC CLASSES
public int id { get; set; }
public string Domain { get; set; }
public int AR { get; set; }
public int Alexa { get; set; }
public string Traffic { get; set; }
public bool Type { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public int Price { get; set; }
public bool Insertion { get; set; }


// Get singular
public bool Get(int DBid)
{
    try
    {
        string connection = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [BLAH].[dbo].[Sources] where id = " + DBid.ToString();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myConnection.Open();
                using (var datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (datareader != null && datareader.Read())
                    {
                        id = Convert.ToInt32(datareader["id"]);
                        Domain = datareader["Domain"].ToString();
                        AR = Convert.ToInt16(datareader["AR"]);
                        Alexa = Convert.ToInt16(datareader["Alexa"]);
                        Traffic = datareader["Traffic"].ToString();
                        Type = Convert.ToBoolean(datareader["Type"]);
                        Category = datareader["Category"].ToString();
                        Country = datareader["Country"].ToString();
                        Price = Convert.ToInt32(datareader["Information"]);
                        Insertion = Convert.ToBoolean(datareader["Insertion"]);

                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have the following the startup:

```
services.AddTransient<dbFuctions>()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you do this:

```
Data.dbFuctions db = new Data.dbFuctions();  // me trying to call the class
```

Don't.  You already have an instance of dbFunctions from this:

```
@inject dbFuctions dbFuctions
```

Just do dbFunctions.*somemethod*.

On another subject, doing DB work in a Transient service is so fraught with danger. There are sooo many ways to leak memory very quickly!  Look out on the Internet for "Blazor Database" for more info on how to do SQL with Blazor.

Comment: Would stored procedures stop the danger? Or would a completely different method like the above be the only solution?

Comment: @MattHodson.  You should consider using Entity Framework see these MSDocs info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/.   If you want to do direct access, use a Scoped or Singleton service and ensure you explicitly open and close DB connections.  Don't rely on IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forget to add your class declaration on the Startup.

In order to use the dependency injection mechanism under .net core you need at least

```cs
services.AddTransient<dbFuctions>()
```

Then you need to inject the class in your razor page code with something like:

```cs
@inject dbFunctions dbFunctions
```

Now you can use your methods without the  *new* keyword.